# organize columns in table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I made a table with this code:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
    \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
    \usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{locale = FR}

    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Equipamentos e normas utilizados nos testes papeleiros com o objectivo de caracterizar as folhas de papel.}
       \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Lcccccc@{}}
        \cmidrule[0.8pt]{1-7}
     Tamanho de Partícula & H60 & H60 M & H90 & H90 M & H90E & H90E M\\
        \cmidrule{1-7}
    \si{d_{50}} (\si{$\mu$m}) & 2,1 & 5,1 & 1,3 & 3,4 & 1,3 & 3,4\\
        \cmidrule[0.8pt]{1-7}
        \end{tabularx}
      \label{d50}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

But I want more space between columns. There are too space between first and others columns. I have some difficuties to explain what I want.

Answer (score 2):

(I've thoroughly revised this answer.)

I think you have three main options:

- Keep using the `tabularx` environment but increase the value of `\tabcolsep`, the length parameter that sets a (hard) amount of inter-column white-space. In the example below I've chosen `12pt` for this parameter, *double* the default value of `6pt`.
- Switch to a `tabular*` environment. Unlike the `tabularx` environment, which operates by expanding the widths of the columns until the overall assigned width (here: `textwidth`) is achieved, `tabular*` works -- if the admittedly arcane-looking directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` is provided -- by expanding the inter-column white-space.

Neither of these two choices is, I believe, perfect, because neither addresses the separate need to align the numerical data on their decimal markers in order to make the information (more) easily parsable. You may therefore want to

- Use a `tabularx` environment with a twist: Use the plain `l` column type for the first column, use the `S` column type (from the `siunitx` package) for the data columns, *and* use a (centered version of the) `X` column type for the headers of each of the six data columns. This will give you good amounts of intercolumn whitespace *and* alignment of the data on the decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = FR}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Equipamentos e normas utilizados nos testes papeleiros com o objectivo de caracterizar as folhas de papel.} \label{d50}

\bigskip
\verb|1. original form |

\verb|   (tabularx, "L" column type for first col., "c" for data columns)|

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Lcccccc@{}}
\cmidrule[0.8pt]{1-7}
Tamanho de Partícula & H60 & H60 M & H90 & H90 M & H90E & H90E M\\
\cmidrule{1-7}
\si{d_{50}} (\si{$\mu$m}) & 2,1 & 5,1 & 1,3 & 3,4 & 1,3 & 3,4\\
\cmidrule[0.8pt]{1-7}
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{12pt}  % default value: 6pt
\verb|2. tabularx with increased value of \tabcolsep|

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{6}{c} @{}}
\midrule[0.8pt]
Tamanho de Partícula & H60 & H60 M & H90 & H90 M & H90E & H90E M\\
\cmidrule{1-7}
\si{d_{50}} (\si{\micro\meter}) & 2,1 & 5,1 & 1,3 & 3,4 & 1,3 & 3,4\\
\bottomrule[0.8pt]
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt} %% choose a deliberately small value
\verb|3. tabular* with @{\extracolsep{\fill}}|

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{6}{c} @{}}
\midrule[0.8pt]
Tamanho de Partícula\quad\null & H60 & H60 M & H90 & H90 M & H90E & H90E M\\
\cmidrule{1-7}
\si{d_{50}} (\si{\micro\meter}) & 2,1 & 5,1 & 1,3 & 3,4 & 1,3 & 3,4\\
\bottomrule[0.8pt]
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} % reset to default value
\verb|4. modified tabularx|

\verb|  "l" for first col., "S" for data columns, "C" for data headers row|

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{6}{S} @{}}
\midrule[0.8pt]
Tamanho de Partícula\quad\null & 
\mc{H60} & \mc{H60 M} & \mc{H90} & 
\mc{H90 M} & \mc{H90E} & \multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{H90E~M}\\
\cmidrule{1-7}
\si{d_{50}} (\si{\micro\meter}) & 2,1 & 5,1 & 1,3 & 3,4 & 1,3 & 3,4\\
\si{d_{500}} (\si{\micro\meter}) & 12,1 & 25,1 & 31,3 & 3,41 & 1,33 & 23,54\\
\bottomrule[0.8pt]
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To increase space between columns you can set the value of the parameter `tabcolsep` by using the following statement inside the `table` environment :  `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}`

```
 \begin{table}[htbp]
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt} %set appropriate space, default is 5pt (most probably).
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} %change vertical spacing of tables
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
 %Table Content
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{This is a caption}
 \label{tab:showingUseOfSpacing}
 \end{table}
```

Comment: In the "standard" document classes, the default value of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt`. Maybe you're thinking of `\arraycolsep` -- its default value is indeed `5pt`.